# PHP Json to HTML with an array on json

Tags: php, json

I have the folowing format of json:

```
[
    {
        "title": "title will be here",
        "teaser": "teaser will be here...",
        "date": ["2015-11-19T00:00:00"]
   }
]
```

and the php to read the json:

```
$json = file_get_contents( "news.json" );
$data = json_decode( $json );
json_decode( json_encode( $data ), true );

foreach ( $data as $object ):
    echo $object->{'title'};
    echo $object->{'teaser'};
    echo $object->{'date'};
endforeach;
```

the code returns title and teaser but not the date, what should i do to return the date correctly?

Comment: The `date` value is an array; you should see a warning `cannot convert Array to string`.

Comment: why decode/encode/decode again? Why not just a single `$data = json_decode($json, true)`? and `'date'` is an array. you can't echo out an array. `$object->date[0]`, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

your date is in an array so $object->date will return an array.
you may only what the first key of the array

```
date: <?= reset($object->date); ?>
```

or output all

```
date: <?php foreach($object->date as $date){echo $date} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The date property is an array. If it only contains 1 valuu, or you only ever want the 1st value, simply access the 1st element:

```
$json=file_get_contents("news.json");
$data =  json_decode($json);
foreach($data as $object):
    echo $object->title;
    echo $object->teaser;
    echo $object->date[0];
endforeach;
```

If you may want to access multiple date values, iterate the array:

```
foreach($data as $object){
    echo $object->title;
    echo $object->teaser;
    foreach($object->date as $date){
        echo $date;
    }
}
```

Note i also removed the erroneous `json_decode(json_encode($data), true);` line and simplified your property access code - all the names are valid property names so no need for the `{'...'}` syntax